# Can you use the return statement as an expression

Tags: javascript

Recently I've discovered that sometimes it is more convenient to

```
condition && fnWhenTrue()
```

than

```
if(condition){
    fnWhenTrue()
}
```

Honestly I've fallen in love with it and started using it wherever it makes sense. However I am unable to do a

```
condition && return
```

As return is a statement and not an expression. Is there a way around this or is this just not a valid use case and I should stop.

I am able to achieve similar effect using an inline if like this

```
if(condition) return
```

But it's just not the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's not a valid use case and you should just stop :).

Comment: I am aware the this can damage the readability, but I try to restrict myself to only use it when evaluating a boolean variable so that I spare myself a lengthy if statement.

Comment: using to replace `if (condition) return` is not one of those 'sparing' case, it's only 2 characters longer, whatever the expression is.

Comment: That's what I did. It bugs me that a proper `if` spans across multiple lines and in the initialization function where this happens I want it to be packed so that with one look you can see all the function calls.

Comment: I don't know why you put `return`. I am using `condition && false`.

Comment: @jacobkim Please elaborate how does this replace `if (condition) return;` in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `return` is not an expression in JavaScript / ECMAScript at the time of this answer.

If you don't want to write several lines / lengthy code, you can use the short `if` notation:

```
if (condition) return;
```

Which is only 2 characters longer than `condition && return;`!

Just as a reminder, `val = exp1 && exp2` is an expression that is roughly equivalent to:

```
let val;
if (exp1) {
  val = exp2;
} else {
  val = exp1;
}
```

(with some main difference that exp1 is evaluated 2 times in my above example, whereas only once in `exp1 && exp2`).

Just as something to convince you that is *probably* intended in JS language design, as you can do:

```
let someResult;
// later...
someResult = exp1 && exp2;
```

then what would `someResult` got as value if you had a `return` instead of exp1 and exp2?